# looping throug multidimensional array and output values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i hope somebody can help me. I read a lot about arrays and tried many of the found examples but i can't get my code to work.

First i create my array like this:

```
$aryUsers= array (
   'users' => 
       array ()
);
```

Than i get some data from my db which i'm saving to my array like this:

```
$user = array("ID" => $ID, "User" => $User, "val" => $val);
$aryUsers["users"][] = $user;
```

If i now **print_r** my array, it look like this:

```
Array ( [users] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => Array ( [ID] => 696 [User] => user 1 [val] => 341 )
        [1] => Array ( [ID] => 708 [User] => user 2 [val] => 218 )
        [2] => Array ( [ID] => 670 [User] => user 3 [val] => 73 )
        [3] => Array ( [ID] => 718 [User] => user 4 [val] => 66 )
        [4] => Array ( [ID] => 698 [User] => user 5 [val] => 66 )
        [5] => Array ( [ID] => 721 [User] => user 6 [val] => 60 )
        [6] => Array ( [ID] => 707 [User] => user 7 [val] => 60 )
        [7] => Array ( [ID] => 720 [User] => user 8 [val] => 141 )
    ) 
)
```

If i try to output my array with the this code (or other i tried), then i get just nothing:

```
$iterations = count($aryUsers[$keys[0]]);
for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
   foreach($aryUsers as $key => $value) {
      echo $value[$i];
   }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Or am I doing something right at all?
Thank u for reading!

Comment: Why are you doing `$iterations = count($aryTeilnehmer[$keys[0]]);`? What does that have to do with `$aryUsers`?

Comment: oh sorry, I've mistyped: $iterations = count($aryUsers[$keys[0]]);
I do this to know how many times i have to loop :/

Comment: You don't need to use for loop. You can simply use `foreach ($aryUsers['users'] as $user) { ... }`

Comment: Please provide your desired output for the above example data. It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi given your sample data data structure.

`$arrayUsers = array ( 
    'users' => array ( 
        0 => array ( 'ID' => 696, 'User' => 'user 1', 'val' => 341 ),
        1 => array ( 'ID' => 708, 'User' => 'user 2', 'val' => 218 ),
        2 => array ( 'ID' => 670, 'User' => 'user 3', 'val' => 73 ),
        3 => array ( 'ID' => 718, 'User' => 'user 4', 'val' => 66 ),
        4 => array ( 'ID' => 698, 'User' => 'user 5', 'val' => 66 ),
        5 => array ( 'ID' => 721, 'User' => 'user 6', 'val' => 60 ),
        6 => array ( 'ID' => 707, 'User' => 'user 7', 'val' => 60 ),
        7 => array ( 'ID' => 720, 'User' => 'user 8', 'val' => 141 ),
    ) 
);`

`foreach ($arrayUsers as $arrayUser) {
    foreach ($arrayUser as $arrayUser) {
        echo $arrayUser['ID']. ' '. $arrayUser['User'] . ' ' . $arrayUser['val'].'<br>';
    }
}`